# Assembly problem

Tags: windows, assembly, masm

I'm trying to multiply 5 decimals using DEBUG in windows command prompt but I fear i've very far off. My program results in the decimal value 1303. When it should be 4320. The decimals are 15, 12, 4, 2, 3.

```
mov al, 15
mov bl, 12
mov bh, 4
mov cl, 2
mov ch, 3
mul ax, bl
mul ax, bh
mul ax, cl
mul ax, ch
aam
```

Comment: Excuse me, but 2*3*4*12*15 is 4320.

Comment: 15*12*4*2*3 = 4320. Why should it be 1303?

Comment: I typed  it wrong that what I want but program returns 1303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing byte x byte multiplies, obviously the intermediate result is going to need more than a byte.  You are also multiplying by AH instead of CH.

Comment: Do i need change it to something like mul ax, [value] ?

Comment: Yes, that avoids the overflow.

Comment: Ok I tried that but still the same result I will post the code im using now in place of the old

Comment: You are not initializing ax properly, the ah register isn't set. And you're still not using CH.  And I don't think that this could even assemble, you'd need a 16x16 multiply.  You need to sleep on this. Tomorrow learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Its due tommorow, thanx for ya help